# Permission denied on tools/python after chocolatey install?

Tags: python, chocolatey

Even though I have admin rights, I continue getting permission denied errors when writing to the files inside my chocolatey python installation. Why, how can I fix that?

```
  PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\tools\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-6.0.8.dist-info\\description.rst'
```

Comment: having admin writes does not mean you will be able to access them by default. u need to run the program with admin rights. I suppose u r running this on windows?

Comment: @Mox Yes, in an Admin console, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is that file not opened?

Comment: @pacholik It doesn't even exist, so I suppose it must be permissions on the folder that are blocking me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the SYSTEM user was assigned owner of the folder, and permissions were set in a way that prevented access, changing of the permissions, etc.

The solution was to [reassign ownership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx) of the folders to the Administrators group/user/whatever. Then I was able to change things. Weird Windows world of permissions.

Comment: How did you run the install? Was it with Puppet/Chef/Boxstarter? It seems that if done as your own user, you would have had permissions. :/

Comment: @ferventcoder with chocolatey, as stated in the question, locally under my own user

Comment: The question doesn't actually state how you performed the install, thus my comment for clarification. You can use Chocolatey on the command line, but you can also use Chocolatey with a number of tools (like Puppet / Chef / Boxstarter). Some of those tools run as services or do PowerShell remoting, and in both cases usually operate as LocalSystem, which would make sense for the reason it was set to SYSTEM user.

Comment: This seems like it's possibly an issue on the python install? I would perhaps follow up on the package page in the disqus thread. Since I'm not sure which of the python packages you installed, I can't really give you a link. :)